# Very simple password encode and decode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a **very simple** password encryption that **doesn't need to be secure**

I currently encode the password with

```
import base64
passwd = "test"
passwd = bytes(passwd, "UTF-8")
passwd = passwd.hex()
passwd = bytes(passwd, "UTF-8")
passwd = base64.b64encode(passwd)
```

if i set "test" as input the output is "b'NzQ2NTczNzQ='"

I'm having problems reversing this. So far i have tried the folloving

```
import base64
passwd = "b'NzQ2NTczNzQ='"
passwd = base64.b64decode(passwd)
passwd = str(passwd).replace("b","").replace("'","")
passwd = bytes(passwd, "UTF-8").hex()
```

But the output of that is "3734363537333734"

Comment: Instead of fiddling with character replacement and bytes and encoding, why not just use encrypt/decrypt functionality from any standard encryption library?

Comment: Well, `passwd = "b'NzQ2NTczNzQ='"` is certainly wrong / nonsense. If anything you need `passwd = b'NzQ2NTczNzQ='`

Comment: You are just randomly adding str, bytes, hex calls all over the place without any sense. `base64.b64encode(bytes("Test", "utf-8"))` and then `base64.b64decode(b'VGVzdA==')`. Done.

Comment: Inverse of `bytes(passwd, "UTF-8")` is `str(passwd, "UTF-8")`. Inverse of method `bytes.hex` is `bytes.fromhex`.

Comment: David : I don't want to use a standard library

luk : I made it simpler to read but in the actual code the two scripts share the passwd variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just reverse each step.

```py
import base64
passwd = b'NzQ2NTczNzQ='
passwd = base64.b64decode(passwd)
passwd = str(passwd, "UTF-8");
passwd = bytes.fromhex(passwd);
passwd = str(passwd, "UTF-8");
```